# How to Open Outlook file attachment directly not saving it? ( with C# VSTO)

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto, attachment

I need to open mail file attachment directly from mail. Let say I have .txt file. I have already attached it to my mail. But now I need to open it, change some words and save it (it is manual part). How can I do this? My code is:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector currInspector = null;
            Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
            Outlook.Attachments attachments = null;



            currInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            if (currInspector != null) { 
            mail = (Outlook.MailItem)currInspector.CurrentItem;
            attachments = mail.Attachments;
            attachments.Add(@"C:\install\CSharp\tulemus.txt", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue);
               

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. You can try to read the attached files from the cache folder maintained by Outlook. See [Finding Outlook temporary folder for email attachments](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/finding-outlook-temporary-folder-for-email/74ff4131-ea10-49b0-81b3-2914850ee0ad?auth=1) for more information.

Also, you can use a low-level API (Extended MAPI) where you can access the [PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagattachdatabinary-canonical-property) property, read more about the algorithm in the [Opening an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/opening-an-attachment) article.

Comment: Note that OOM won't let you access large ( >32 kB) MAPI properties using the PropertyAccessor object.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I didn't mention OOM in my post actually. Extended MAPI allows gettin access to large properties using streams and etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Eugene suggested - use `Attachment.PropertyAccessor` or MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to access the `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102"`) - you can also use Redemption (I am its author): its [RDOAttach](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsText` / `AsArray` / `AsStream` properties allow to modify attachment contents on the fly

Comment: OOM won't let you access large ( >32 kB) MAPI properties using the PropertyAccessor object. So, as I stated in my post, the possible alternative is to use a low-level property (Extended MAPI). The [Opening an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/opening-an-attachment) explains how to do that.