# How can I download attachments from emails sent as attachments with Python?

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I received an email with multiple emails attached. Each email has .xls file that I want to download.

How can I do this in Python?

(I use the Outlook app)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqQ2.png)

I tried to move these emails to my inbox and run the code I already use:

```
path = 'C:/Users/moliveira/Desktop/projeto_email'
    os.chdir(path)
    output_dir = Path.cwd()
    output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    mapi=outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    messages = inbox.Items
    received_dt = datetime.now() - BDay(600)
    date_aux = received_dt
    date = received_dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    Subject = 'OPÇÕES RV - '+date
    received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + " 13:00 PM" + "'")
    messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] <= '" + received_dt + " 23:59 PM" + "'")


    messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = "+Subject)
    try:
        for message in list(messages):
            try:
                s = message.sender
                for attachment in message.Attachments:
                    attachment.SaveASFile(os.path.join(output_dir, attachment.FileName))
                    print(f"attachment {attachment.FileName} from {s} saved")
            except Exception as e:
                print("error when saving the attachment:" + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
            print("error when processing emails messages:" + str(e))        
    date = date_aux.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
    list(messages)
```

But the return of list(messages) is empty, meaning that it's not locating the email.
I think it's because I have to "click to view more on Microsoft Exchange". Just after this I can see these emails in the app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVYp1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the attached item to the disk and then execute it programmatically to be opened in Outlook (it is a singleton which means only one instance of Outlook can be run at the same time).

Also if the attached mail item is saved to the disk you may use the [NameSpace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) method which opens a shared item from a specified path or URL. This method is used to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files. So, you will get an instance of the `MailItem` class which represents the attached Outlook item.

TO distinguish Outlook items and regular files attached to the message use the [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type) property which equals to the `olEmbeddeditem` value when the attachment is an Outlook message format file (.msg) and is a copy of the original message.

If you wants to open them without saving on the disk, see [How to Open Outlook file attachment directly not saving it? ( with C# VSTO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029559/how-to-open-outlook-file-attachment-directly-not-saving-it-with-c-sharp-vsto). In short, you can try to read the attached files from the cache folder maintained by Outlook. See [Finding Outlook temporary folder for email attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029559/how-to-open-outlook-file-attachment-directly-not-saving-it-with-c-sharp-vsto) for more information. Also, you can use a low-level API (Extended MAPI) where you can access the [PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029559/how-to-open-outlook-file-attachment-directly-not-saving-it-with-c-sharp-vsto) property, read more about the algorithm in the [Opening an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63029559/how-to-open-outlook-file-attachment-directly-not-saving-it-with-c-sharp-vsto) article.